# File upload doesn't work when giving the absolute path when using a a text box to upload python Django

Tags: python, django

I have a web application written in Python and Django framework that allows uploading a file. The uploaded file path is shown in a textbox. When I browse and select a file it is shown as *c:\fakepath\Sample.docx* in the textbox and when I click the upload button the file upload happens hassle-free.

But if I provide the absolute path in the textbox as *C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\sample.docx* and click the upload button, the file doesn't upload.

Html code to create the upload in a textbox:

```
<input id="txt" type = "text" value = "Choose File" size="40" align="center"
       onclick ="javascript:document.getElementById('file').click();">
<input id = "file" type="file" style='visibility: hidden;' name="file1" 
       onchange="ChangeText(this, 'txt'); Filevalidation()">
```

Python code when I try to extract the file uploaded

```
file = request.FILES['file1']
```

Error while giving the absolute path:

> raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)
>   django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'file1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because you're not sending any actual file in the request by just typing the file path, so, that 'file1' key is not filled in the request.FILE dictionary. So, you can do:

```
file = request.FILES.get('file1', '')
```

This will handle the case when that key does not exist and give a default value (if not passed, default would be None).

But still, doing this just avoid getting the error, but the file won't be sent anyways. You can't send a file to the server by just writing the path where it is stored.

Comment: Ok it makes sense.